# Facebook Graph API has stopped working for photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/photos` but looks like it has stopped working correctly in UI.

The endpoint returns the response with publication ID, but the photo is not shown on the Page. I can only see the uploaded photo from inside my admin account, which means the uploaded photo is not publicly available.

Example:

```
POST request example:
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/photos?access_token=...
Body:
caption=text
ulr=photo url
no_story=false
published=true
```

the response:

```
{
"id": "6851823568176784",
"post_id": "132553756770499_6851823568176784"
}
```

Even if I use GET for `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/photos` it shows the recently uploaded photo. However, Page still doesn't have it.

I even posted a bug to Developers Platform: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/986155901938240/

However, the response was: *From backend, I can confirm that both photos are created properly (since these were id returned). This seems to be an Facebook.com UI issue.*

Has anyone also spotted this?

Comment: Your app needs to be in live mode, if it is still in dev mode, then any content created via it will only be visible to people with a role in your app.

Comment: this app is in prod since 2018 :)